# I have Crépin with character é in database stored? How can I display the same character?

Tags: php, utf-8, drupal-8

I need to convert é this into readable form in drupal 8 .The character is shown as � instead of é. Which function can be used to display é in the html while fetching value from database.?

I tried using many functions but did not suceed in implementing it
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Component!Utility!Html.php/function/Html%3A%3AdecodeEntities/8
http://php.net/html_entity_decode

Comment: Is there character correct in the DB? Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through.

Comment: yes in db the character is  é. checking the link @chris85

Comment: Great !!!! This $mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');       // object oriented style
worked for me.!! Awesome Man!!!

Comment: I've marked it as a duplicate of that other thread. It is better to link to the other thread because there is a lot more information there. If others find this thread and are having the same issue it will help them too.

Comment: @chris85 Thank you for that link.  Excelent piece of information. ALso the links it contains. I am in the process of upgrading a LATIN-9 postgres 7 database to this age. Things get often pretty confusing, and your link summed a LOT up nicely.